# Periodogram/PSD from FFT amplitude

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum, power-spectral-density, window-functions, scipy

I have performed a STFT for signals and obtained the amplitude through

```
S = librosa.stft(y=y_cut,n_fft=n_fft,win_length=n_fft,hop_length=n_fft,window='hann',center=False)
```

Here i have 4097 rows for S (1 + NFFT/2) and 12 colums (time periods).

I want to obtain the PSD from this. PSD is the square of magnitude, but I have values over time period and I have to take mean of them. I have 2 methods to proceed.

Method 1: Taking amplitude mean in the time frames and then squaring the amplitude

```
Abs_mean = np.mean(Abs, axis = 1) # Mean
Power_dB =librosa.power_to_db(Abs_mean**2)   # dB
```

Method 2: squaring the amplitudes and then taking the mean of power

```
Power_mean = np.mean(Abs**2,axis=1) # Mean of amplitude^2
Power_dB =librosa.power_to_db(Power_mean) # dB
```

Which method is correct?

Comment: Generally the second. Take the mean of the power. Your hop_length seems wrong for a hann window. Try n_fft/2.

Comment: Thank. I want a window with no overlap and that is why i have set the ```hop_length = n_fft = win_length``` Does this makes sense?

Comment: No it doesn't. Most windows work best with a 50% overlap. The window tapers off the ends of the current frame so the samples at the edge of the frame are underrepresented. You compensate this by putting these samples in the middle of the previous/next frame